# WPF Passwordbox - Internal error when debugging?

Tags: c#, wpf

**UPDATE:**

Due to the help from [Devid Farinelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4695325/devid-farinelli) I was able to sort it out myself. [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debugger/2010/05/11/visual-studio-debugger-fails-to-catch-unhandled-exception-for-a-windows-form-or-wpf-application/) link helps to point out the issue but the described Workaround doesn't fit to Visual Studio 2015. If you're having the problem there, refer to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/02/23/the-new-exception-settings-window-in-visual-studio-2015/) link. In my specific case it was a line where I called a control property without invoking the thread before. Not a big thing but with the error it was. Hope this helps some others maybe.

Thanks and greetings

I'm using a PasswordBox in a UserControl.
To detect the user has entered both his username and a password, I'm disabling the Login button as long as one of both is empty.
So far, so good, all is working as expected, the button gets enabled if both are containing something.

The thing is: I wanted to debug the method in behind code where I'm changing the button state but I'm getting an "internal error" message like:

> Event-ID=0x20c. Exception code=0xc0000005, Eip=0x7226b264.

That's not the usual exception message window.

My method code on this is just

```
        private void txtCheckLoginEnable(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbPassword.SecurePassword.Length > 0 && tbUser.Text != "")
            cmdLogin.SetValue(Button.IsEnabledProperty, true);
        else
            cmdLogin.SetValue(Button.IsEnabledProperty, false);
    }
```

The event gets called from one of both TextBoxes. And as said, if not placing a stop point inside the method, nothing pops up.

Someone an idea on this? I'm not sure if it's an issue functionwise but as said, I'm not getting other bugs from it.

Comment: Does [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debugger/2010/05/11/visual-studio-debugger-fails-to-catch-unhandled-exception-for-a-windows-form-or-wpf-application/) help you to get to the bottom of the issue?

Comment: It did.. somehow at least. The link doesn't count for the 2015 version. I'll update my question with the issue I had. Thanks tough of course!

Comment: please post your solution as the answer so others will be able to find & use it - you are welcome on SO to answer your own questions in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

Due to the help from Devid Farinelli I was able to sort it out myself. [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debugger/2010/05/11/visual-studio-debugger-fails-to-catch-unhandled-exception-for-a-windows-form-or-wpf-application/) link helps to point out the issue but the described Workaround doesn't fit to Visual Studio 2015. If you're having the problem there, refer to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/02/23/the-new-exception-settings-window-in-visual-studio-2015/) link. In my specific case it was a line where I called a control property without invoking the thread before. Not a big thing but with the error it was. Hope this helps some others maybe.

Thanks and greetings